# How to get access control of C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config folder using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to give permission to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config folder. But when I use the below code it throws exception "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."

```
 string desktopFolderPath = @"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config";

        FileSystemAccessRule iis_iusrs = new FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS",
           FileSystemRights.FullControl,
           InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
           PropagationFlags.None,
           AccessControlType.Allow);

        FileSystemAccessRule networkService = new FileSystemAccessRule("NETWORK SERVICE",
            FileSystemRights.FullControl,
            InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
            PropagationFlags.None,
            AccessControlType.Allow);

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo desktopFolderDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(desktopFolderPath);
        DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = null;

directorySecurity = desktopFolderDirectory.GetAccessControl(); -- **Exception**
            directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(iis_iusrs);
            directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(networkService);
            desktopFolderDirectory.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);
```

Please help if anyone can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you executing the code as an admin user?

Comment: why do you want to access windows level foleer from your asp.net site?

Comment: @Jim I want to run this code on client machine, so I am not admin user but i want to perform these actions. How can i do that?

Comment: @programtreasures This is related to my previous question that was to recycle Application Pool. But for that I need to give permissions to IIS_IUSRS, so I need to access config folder of client to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder path `Properties` and make sure it Read-only check box is unchecked. [image: inetsrv properties]

> This may be of some help: [link](https://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/workaround-running-asp-net-1-1-on-vista-sp2-ws08-sp2)
>
> If it doesn't, then try sharing the folder.
>
> By the way it is a system folder, It may not be accessible, so try hosting pages in `C:\inetpub`

Comment: ok, try reading this: [link](https://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/workaround-running-asp-net-1-1-on-vista-sp2-ws08-sp2) - it may help